# Socket.io Nodejs CoffeeScript getting both socket and current inherited class variable in socket.on

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I ran into a problem where I need both socket and class instance but can't get them.
I have configuration file where are events like : message, post, share. I have the following code:

```
module.exports = class Controller

    constructor : (container) ->
        @_routes = null

    _generateRoutes : (routes) ->
        @_routes = routes

    _bind : (socket) ->
        instance = @
        for route in @_routes
            # TODO : fix this
            socket.on route['event'], (data) ->
                instance[route['action']](@, data)
```

The problem is, I can call any event from that table, it always ends up in share event. I think it could be problem in instance[route['action]]. Is there a way to explicitly say I want just a value of variable, not the current variable in the function?

So every time I can get just socket while binding the socket action directly or just class instance while using => in inherited class.

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized what is wrong with that code. It should use closure. For closures, there is a keyword in coffeescript "do". Then, it won't use changing value of route but local value in each loop.

Fixed _bind function looks like this :

```
    _bind : (socket) ->
    instance = @
    for route in @_routes
            do (route)->
                socket.on route['event'], (data) -> 
                    instance[route['action']](@, data)
```